# Selenium popup issue in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I cannot handle authentication popups in **Chrome** because these are being shown **before the page finishes loading**, so the `ChromeDriver` gets stucked in:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

and this call cannot finish. I tried enclosing the call in a **Task** and continuing, but the next time the driver is accessed the execution pauses till the `GoToUrl` call finishes (which never happen till the popup is closed).

Any ideas to workaround this?

[image]

Comment: Here is what I suggest: use `Try Catch` block, in Try block open the URL but limit the `pageLoadTimeout` and in catch block, check if popup exist and close if exist.

Comment: You may want to try this: `driver.get("http://username:password@url");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to modify headers with your request. 
See f.i.: https://eveningsamurai.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/changing-http-headers-for-a-selenium-webdriver-request/ where a plugin extension is used to modify the headers of your request.

I think your solution is in adding the correct headers or modifying them. A Google search on this topic will give you plenty of possible options.